# Azure function upload failing with "A task was canceled"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am getting the following error when using the following command to upload my function app:

```
 func azure functionapp publish FuncAppName
```

I ran this from both the parent directory of the function app and the function app directory itself, and got the same error. It looks like some task in the upload times out after a minute or so:

```
Publish C:\Users\username\Documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\AzureFuncApp contents to an Azure Function App. Locally deleted files are not removed from destination.
Getting site publishing info...
Creating archive for current directory...
Uploading archive...
A task was canceled.
```

Any idea how to solve this/get more debugging info?

The function in question already exists on Portal and is running. I was previously able to upload it successfully.

Comment: You can set env var `CLI_DEBUG` to `1` and it'll print full stack trace. how persistent is this error? there was a recent fix to improve the reliability of the publish command by retrying http requests that may fail but it hasn't been release yet. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/commit/b2e05d267310d7003b975ab9d77428b1abe75465

Comment: Could you give this suggestion a try https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/147

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/147

A change has been made to address this issue and will be included in the next CLI release.